# How to prune a pyspark dataframe from the rows that meet certain conditions

Tags: python, pyspark

I am pretty new in pyspark, so any help is appreciated. I am trying iterate through a pyspark Dataframe, and filter it out from the rows that meet certain rules.

The Dataframe looks like this:

```
root
 |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- email: string (nullable = true)
 |-- status: string (nullable = true)
 |-- foo: string (nullable = true)
 |-- bar: decimal(36,16) (nullable = true)
 |-- foobar: decimal(36,16) (nullable = true)
 |-- decision: string (nullable = true)
 |-- spam: string (nullable = true)
 |-- foobarfoo: decimal(36,16) (nullable = true)
 |-- shop: long (nullable = true)
 |-- dt: timestamp (nullable = true)
```

This is what I could come up so far, but this does not accomplish the task:

```
def rules_check(arow,alist):
    for i in alist:
        rules_1 = [i['shop'] == arow['shop'],
                   i['email'] == arow['email'],
                   ((i['dt'] - arow['dt']).days <=1),
                   (i['decision'] == 'declined' and arow['decision'] == 'declined')]
        rules_2 = [i['shop'] == arow['shop'],
                   i['email'] == arow['email'],
                   ((i['dt'] - arow['dt']).days <=1),
                   (i['decision'] == 'accepted' and arow['decision'] == 'declined')]
        if any((rules_1,rules_2)):
            return True
        
def check_st(alist,aset):
    for i in alist:
        if aset.issubset(set(i)):
            print(f'There is a match')
            return True
        
def prune_df(sdf):
    rem_idx = []
    store = []
    idx = [0,1,2,6,10]
    for i in sdf.collect():
        if all((check_st(store,set(list(map(i.__getitem__,idx))[1:])), rules_check(i,store))):
            rem_idx.append(i['id'])
        else:
            store.append(i)
    pruned_sdf = sdf.filter(~sdf.id.isin(rem_idx))
    return pruned_sdf
```

This code above returns back the dataframe without pruning the rows that fitting the category. I assume the bug is around `if aset.issubset(set(i)):` statement since it does not print `There is a match` although I am aware that there are several matches in the dataset.

Comment: I suspect you are taking the wrong approach by performing a row by row operation here. You should be able to simply articulate in terms of `df.filter(my_rules)`. Perhaps you could articulate your question in terms of what you are trying to filter from your data frame

Comment: I agree with @chris.
 You are trying to collect the data to the driver and then performing the operation. Instead of the i would suggest you to do filter operation using dataframe.
Refer this link https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-where-filter/